# Executing a proc which saves tran in a transaction got error of "mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created the following stored procedure.

```
alter proc test
as
if @@trancount = 0
begin
    begin tran test;
end;
else
begin
    save tran test;
end;

-- ......

if @@trancount > 0
begin
    print formatmessage('trancount %d', @@trancount);
    commit tran test;
    print formatmessage('commit %d', @@trancount);
end;
```

It works when `exec dbo.test`. However, the following code got the following error?

```
begin tran; 
exec dbo.test;
rollback; -- Or commit
```

> Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure test, Line 19
>
> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.
>
> Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
>
> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

Comment: [This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187844(v=sql.105).aspx) might be helpful: `If @@TRANCOUNT has a different value when a stored procedure finishes than it had when the procedure was executed, an informational error (266) occurs.` Likewise, since stored procedures are technically batches in themselves, and you're skipping the part where you begin the transaction, it will throw an error for that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAVE TRAN does not create a nested transaction, so when you COMMIT TRAN you are commiting the transaction that was started outside the proc. And that is not allowed, producting that error.

If you want to SAVE TRAN in the proc, then you don't commit, you just ROLLBACK to the savepoint on error.

Comment: Got it. I think what I need is actually nested transaction.

Comment: *SAVE TRAN does not create a nested transaction, so when you COMMIT TRAN you are commiting the transaction that was started outside the proc*. Ok so then why does the error say *The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.*--Why does it not commit the one started outside?

Comment: `Why does it not commit the one started outside?` It does, and you're not allowed to do that, thus the error.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, I will need to get rid of save tran

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft got it. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I get rid of `save tran` but now it got a strange issue on `rollback` only. A new question has been posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412586/rollback-in-the-nested-transactions-causes-the-error-of-no-transaction-or-savep

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows a way to create a proc which can be commit/rollback its transactions and be executed in or not in another transaction.

```
alter proc test @rollback bit = 1
as
declare @trancount int = @@trancount;
if @trancount = 0
begin
    begin tran test;
end;
else
begin
    save tran test;
end;

-- ......

if @@trancount > 0
begin 
    if @trancount = 0
    begin 
        print 'no external tran';
        if @rollback = 1
            rollback;
        else
            commit;
    end;
    else
    begin 
        print formatmessage('trancount %d', @@trancount);
        if @rollback = 0
        begin
            -- commit tran test;
            print 'just return';
        end;
        else
        begin
            rollback tran test;
            print 'rollback';
        end;
        print formatmessage('after %d', @@trancount);
    end;
end;
go
```